# Power BI pass parameters to report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a Power BI report which has several parameters, I have a requirement to embed the report in a web page and would like to set those parameters via the embed URL or the Power BI JavaScript library. Is this possible? Fundamentally I'd like to pass some data from the page which hosts the report to the report and access that data in M. Is there any mechanism to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript library to apply filters. Lets assume you have a PowerBI report and some state data in a table called "Sample Data with State" that has a column named "State" and you want to use the javascript API to filter by state values.

HTML

```
<p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Parameters" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Parameters
    </button>
</p>

<div class="collapse" id="Parameters">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <div id="state-picker"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Javascript

report.on("loaded", function (event) {

```
report.on('loaded', function() {
    report.render();
    populateStatePicker();

    $("#state-picker input").click(setStateFilter);

});

var selectStates = function (states) {

  $("#state-picker input").each(function () {
    var state = $(this).prop('id');
    var selectState = (states.indexOf(state) > -1);
    $(this).prop('checked', selectState);
  });

  setStateFilter();
}


var unselectAllStates = function () {

  $("#state-picker input:checked").each(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });

  setStateFilter();
}

var populateStatePicker = function () {

  var states = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'];

  $("#state-picker").empty();

  for (var index = 0; index < states.length; index++) {
    var state = states[index];
    $("#state-picker")
      .append($("<div>", { class: "state-container" })
        .append($("<input>", { id: state, name: state, type: "checkbox", class: "state-checkbox" }))
        .append($("<label>", { for: state, class: "state-label" }).text(state))
      );
  }
}

var setStateFilter = function () {

  var states = [];
  $("#state-picker input:checked").each(function () {
    states.push($(this).attr("name"));
  });

  if (states.length > 0) {

    const basicStateFilter = {
      $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
      target: {
        table: "Sample Data with State",
        column: "State"
      },
      operator: "In",
      values: states
    }

    // apply filter to report
    report.setFilters([basicStateFilter]);
  }
  else {
    report.removeFilters();
  }

};
```

This will give you a parameter box on the UI of state values. As you click them the PowerBI report will update its filters based on what you clicked.

Enjoy.